# form dropdown required codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i have code like this

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
 <?php $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "actype"';
echo form_dropdown('actype',$actype,set_value('actype',$detail[0]>activity_type),$attributes);?>
</div>
```

my model:

```html
function get_actype()
 {
  $type_id = array('-SELECT-');
  $type_name = array('-SELECT-');

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
  {
   array_push($type_id, $result[$i]->activity_type_id);
   array_push($type_name, $result[$i]->activity_type_name);
  }
  return $actype_result = array_combine($type_id, $type_name);

 }
```

how to create validate dropdown required

Comment: show your controller code also

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: help of you see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866416/dropdown-required-not-working-in-codeigniter/39866632#39866632

Comment: you better go with `form_validation->set_rules();`